# what is the benefit of using super object in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was studying code igniter. and i come across this super object.

Code igniter has a function that load classes and store them in a instance variable. Each time we need to include a new class or previously loaded class, code igniter searches it first in instance array and if not found then load it and include in instanc array.

My question is in class when we can include class by load_class function( since this function first searches in insntance array, so reducing the overhead of including same class again and again,) so what is the need for declaring super object to include predefined or loading new classes.

When we can do this.

```
class CLASSNAME
{
  function functionname()
  {
     $object = load_class(classname, location);
     $object->callfunction();
  }
}
```

So why we need to do this

```
class CLASSNAME
{
  function functionname()
  {
    $superobject = & get_instance();
    $superobject->classobject->function(); 
  }
}
```

Just want to know the benefit of using super object. Is it just to include all predefined objects, or something more deeper and beneficial that i wasn't able to understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use already existing objects instead of duplicating them. Should speed things up since you won't have duplicate data.

Comment: Yes thats what i want to know the benefits of super object. Is this (using existing defined object for each class instead of new, so that every class has only one object) the only benefit, or some more benefits also lies there. And if i am not wrong then there is no problem to define a new object in a "target class" for including another "required class" as the object scope remain within class scope.

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you've given (if you only need a reference to a library) - there's no benefit. `get_instance()` is just a more common (and documented) function, while `load_class()` is just for internal use.

The possible benefit is that `get_instance()` gives you access to *everything* that your controller has, if for example you want to check a controller property, call a model method, etc.

Comment: I was trying to understand the inner working of code igniter. There i got stuck with the use of super object, and was little confuse, what i got from my understanding is that code igniter team created the concept of super object to allow its user to define class with the controller. And the load_object is a function that is used to initialize the primary and important classes for the working of code igniter framework.

Comment: So i reach to a conclusion that if someone is creating a small framework for their website. as i am creating, so with load_class concept we can do it, and is not required to go with a super object concept, as with a small modification to this function of load_class we can utilize it for more broader purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to have a class and extend another class for inherit. Like this:

```
class Car extends Garage {
  // properties and functions
}
```

But in **Codeigniter** you must extends *`CI_Controller`* for loading libraries, helpers etc.

For using both (extending your own class beside loading CodeIgniter’s native resources) you can use super object. An example:

```
class Car extends Garage {

    protected $CI;

    // We'll use a constructor, as you can't directly call a function
    // from a property definition.
    public function __construct()
    {
            // Assign the CodeIgniter super-object
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function foo()
    {
            $this->CI->load->helper('url');
            redirect();
    }

    public function bar()
    {
            $this->CI->config->item('base_url');
    }
}
```

See [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html):

> In some cases you may want to develop classes that exist apart from your controllers but have the ability to utilize all of CodeIgniter’s resources. This is easily possible as you’ll see.